# ngrx effect doesn't run if the action is dispatched from another module

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-entity

So here's what i'm trying to do.

Under a lazy-loaded `BookmarksModule` feature module, i have an effect that listens to `authActions.loginSuccess` w/c is registered in a `AuthModule` w/c is not lazy-loaded.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FavoriteEffects {
  getFavoriteAfterLogin$ = createEffect(
    () => {
      return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(authActions.loginSuccess),
        map(() => favoriteActions.getFavorites())
      );
    }
  );
```

Here's how the `authActions.loginSuccess` is dispatched.

```js
loginCallback$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.loginCallback),
    exhaustMap(() =>
      this.authService.currentUser$.pipe(
        map(currentUser => authActions.loginSuccess({ currentUser })),
        catchError(error =>
          of(authActions.loginFailure({ error: error?.error?.message }))
        )
      )
    )
  );
});

loginSuccessRedirect$ = createEffect(
  () => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(authActions.loginSuccess),
      tap(() => this.router.navigate([this.redirects.login.success]))
    );
  },
  { dispatch: false }
);
```

As you can see, when `authActions.loginSuccess` is dispatched, it's correctly intercepted by `loginSuccessRedirect$` within the same class but this actions is not intercepted within a lazy-loaded module?

This is the screenshot of the actions in ngrx store devtools
[image]

It seems like the `update-reducers` action for the feature module is dispatched **AFTER** the `loginSuccess` action has already been dispatched.

How do i fix this one?

Comment: Since BookmarksModule is lazy loaded module so it’s effect is not loaded yet, as a result the effect did not get called. The effect will be called when the BookmarksModule is loaded. You can try it.

Comment: @user2216584 , how should i do it in this case, if need to listen to the action from the eager loaded module?

Comment: Is BooknarksModule is angular feature module or ngrx feature Module? If it is a ngrx feature module then you need to eager load it. If it’s an angular feature module then you cannot do whatever you are trying to achieve, you will have to change the design a bit.

Comment: yup, the BookmarksModule is a feature module. Basically what i want is after login, i want to dispatch a certain action.